# Filter out Configurable Products in layered navigation who have out of stock filtered option

Tags: configurable-product, layered-navigation, stock

Currently my store configured to show out of stock products and I need to keep it that way.

The only exception for hiding products is when:

1. Using the layered navigation is the category page
2. The filtered product is of type configurable
3. The filtered option is out of stock in that product

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possibly related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4743/layered-navigation-filters-for-grouped-products-only?rq=1